# AppStore not launching from within an iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, iphone, iframe

A web app that we're developing is designed to be embedded into another website and there is a button on one of the screens that open either PlayStore or AppStore depending on the user platform. It works fine on Android but it doesn't seem to work on iOS, nothing happens when the button is clicked.
We tried the same directly from the web app and it worked, so it seems that iframe is the issue

Here is the click handler function

```
  const handleDownloadAppStore = () => {
       window.location.href = 'https://apps.apple.com/no/app/idxxxxxxxx';
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

First, need to check your  user agent as it iOS/iPad, for them url is different
put a condition over there it is iPad/iOS use below url

**"https://itunes.apple.com/app/your-app-id"**